# ModelMapper Provider ignored on first level properties of a mapping

Tags: modelmapper

I have already successfully used a Provider in a ModelMapper transformation but I've stumbled upon a weird situation. I've noticed that the Provider is being considered only for the objects beyond the "first level" of the transformation, eg.:
 I have two hierarchies:
1st) TipoConsultarProcessoResposta, TipoProcessoJudicial and TipoDocumento
2nd) ConsultarProcessoResposta, ProcessoJudicial and Documento
TipoConsultarProcessoResposta has a TipoProcessoJudicial that in turn has a List of TipoDocumento, the 2nd hierarchy ressembles the first.
I am converting from the first hierarchy to the second and the provider is working fine for the TipoDocumento to Documento conversion but it is being ignored for the conversion of TipoProcessoJudicial to ProcessoJudicial.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
    modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(STRICT);
    modelMapper.addMappings(new DocumentoPropertyMap()).setProvider(documentoProvider);
    modelMapper.addMappings(new ProcessoJudicialPropertyMap()).setProvider(processoJudicialProvider);

    ConsultarProcessoResposta resposta = modelMapper.map(tipoConsultarProcessoResposta, ConsultarProcessoResposta.class);
```

`DocumentoPropertyMap extends PropertyMap<TipoDocumento, Documento> and ProcessoJudicialPropertyMap extends PropertyMap<TipoProcessoJudicial, ProcessoJudicial>.`

The thing is that the DocumentoProvider is being called but ProcessoJudicialProvider isn't being called. ModelMapper tries to invoke a Global Provider that fails as well and resorts to instantiating through the constructor.

Comment: I tried to setup a smaller project to reproduce this problem but it seems like some other configuration is affecting the overall scenario.

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested in seeing the tests I've setup... https://github.com/rafaelri/modelmapper-provider-issue-tests

Comment: I have a similar problem...provider is completely ignored for some reason